# Average Student Grades from txt in Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a text file where I have the names in the first 2 columns and 4 random grades in the next 4 column. I have to calculate the average of a "student" I give in argument.

Text file looks like this:

```
John Xander 2 2 4 4
... ...     . . . .
```

So if I have the argument "John Xander" it should give me back (2 + 2 + 4 + 4) / 4 = 3

I have the part to read the text and the name from argument but I can't give the grades to the name. I tried to cut the grades to 4 different vars then calculate with those. Now this code gives me an error because the avg part is wrong, but if I tried to echo a,b,c,d it gave me the third column then 3 empty line.

```
while read p;
do
  x=$(echo $p | cut -d ' ' -f 1,2)
  if [ "$x" = "$1" ]
  then
    a=`cut -d ' ' -f 3`
    b=`cut -d ' ' -f 4`
    c=`cut -d ' ' -f 5`
    d=`cut -d ' ' -f 6`
    avg=$(( ($a + $b + $c + $d) / 4 ))
    echo $avg
  fi
done < class.txt
```

EDIT: Thanks for the help it works, I only have 1 thing left to do and it is to echo out all the names that's in the file if the name given in the argument isn't in the file.

Comment: You haven't given any input to to `a=\`cut -d ' ' -f 3\` `

Answer (score 0):

Don't use all those `cut` commands to split the line. You forgot to use `echo "$p"` in them. Since you didn't pipe anything to them, the first one reads the rest of the file from stdin and the rest have nothing to read.

Just read all the fields of the line directly into variables.

```
while read -r fname lname a b c d
do
    x="$fname $lname"
    if [ "$x" = "$1" ]
    then
        avg=$(( (a + b + c + d) / 4 ))
        echo "$avg"
        break
    fi
done < class.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this relatively easily with awk:

```
awk -v nam="John Xander" 'match($0,nam) { print ($3+$4+$5+$6)/4 }' file
```

Pass a variable nam into awk. Using nam, check if there is a match in the line. If there is, take the third, fourth, fifth and sixth space delimited fields, add them, divide by 4 and print the result.